# getline and passing input streams inside class functions, primary-expression error

Tags: c++, token, iostream

I have a file called grades.txt with some lines of text and integers on it that i want to read into an already defined class ive created called Assignment.

```
int main()
{
  ifstream input_file("grades.txt");
  Assignment assignment;

  input_file >> assignment;
  return 0;
}
```

Above is my main function that will read input_file into the created class assignment.

```
friend istream& operator >> (istream& is, Assignment& assignment)
  { // function to read in data to class variables                                      
    string line;
    getline(*****, line);

    // to be able to operate on strings                                                 
    istringstream iss(line);

    // set values read in from input file.                                              
    iss >> assignment.Assignment_type;
    iss >> assignment.Date;
    iss >> assignment.Max_score;
    iss >> assignment.Actual_score;
    // sometimes Assignment Name will have spaces, have to use getline()                
    getline(is, assignment.Assignment_name);
    return is;
  }
```

Heres the class function that will overload the >> operator to read into each of the variables in assignment. the group of stars is what im having problems with, i dont know what to pass to it. I've tried ifstream and ofstream thinking it was that easy but they return the same error code

```
P01.cpp:34:21: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
```

Comment: your use of `friend` makes no sense. This is obviously a global function, but friends can only be declared inside a class. What is this a friend of? It's best to avoid friends altogether by having your `operator>>` simply use public methods.

Comment: I also assume you have a `using std::istream;` somewhere, else you need to use `std::istream` instead of just `istream`.

Comment: shouldn't you pass your in stream to it?  as in `getline(is,line);`

Comment: @Adam im sorry i shouldve been more detailed - This is a call function inside class Assignment - friend is used correctly because the values Assignment_type, Date, etc etc are in the private: block

Comment: No it's not used correctly, because this function CANNOT be a member of Assignment. So you can declare it as a friend inside Assignment, but you must define it outside of the class without the `friend` keyword.

Comment: @Chemistpp you are 100% correct thank you -  ive been staring at this computer for too long.

Comment: @nastalgia np, good luck.  You're on your own for this `friend` declaration everyone seems to be harping about.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you defined these operator `>>` inside the `class Assignment`. Only declare it as friend, but put the definition somewhere out: it is not a member of `Assignment`. The error is telling you that Operator `>>` take only one argument when defined as a member (the right operand, becouse the link is `this`). 
Als "namespace" or global function it accept two arguments: link and right.